What free objective tools can be used for assessing pronunciation?
I'm also interested in fluency and intonation.
Any insights will be wonderful.

What exactly are you trying to assess?

Assess learners' ability to pronounce specific sounds and determine how understandable their spoken English. As well the smoothness and rhythm of the speech without unnecessary pauses or hesitations.

Maybe [languagelearning.se] is a better place to ask for this

I'll try there, thanks .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
